# How to select multiple columns with 1 column with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables namely tbl_votes and tbl_candidates:

tbl_votes: contains the ff column:

```
voteID    president    vicePresident    secretary    treasurer    rep1    rep2     rep3
1             1              3                                     9       12       15
2             1              4              6            8         12      15
3             2              3              5            7         9       12
```

while tbl_candidates contain the ff column:

```
idcandidate  fName         mName         lName         position
1            Jefferson     Garcia        Roxas         president
2            Carlson       Mcvoy         Zafiro        president
3            Andrew        Efron         Anderson      vice president
4            Jessica       Garcia        Roxas         secretary
```

...

```
9            Jayson        Sanchez       Dela Cruz      representative
10           Arille Alisa  Villanueva    Valdez         representative
11           Arnold        Castro        Baltazar       representative
12           Kristina      de Leon       Guillermo      representative
13           Jayson        Jones         Dela Cruz      representative
14           Karla         Santos        Abrogena       representative
15           Jason                       Chua           representative
```

The query that I want to is:

```
Name                                                       votes
Jefferson Garcia Roxas                                       2
Carlson Mcvoy Zafiro                                         1
Andrew Efron Anderson                                        2
Jessica Garcia Roxas                                         1
```

...

```
Jayson Sanchez Dela Cruz                                     2
Arnold Castro Baltazar                                       0
Kristina de Leon Guillermo                                   3
Jason  Chua                                                  2
```

I'm stuck where to count the votes and here is my codes:

```
SELECT `Name`, Votes
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as Votes FROM tbl_votes) a
CROSS JOIN (Select (Concat(fName ,' ',mName,' ', lName)) as `Name` from tbl_candidates) b;
```

the result of this query is:

```
Name                                                       Votes
Jefferson Garcia Roxas                                       3
Carlson Mcvoy Zafiro                                         3
Andrew Efron Anderson                                        3
Jessica Garcia Roxas                                         3
Jayson Sanchez Dela Cruz                                     3
Arnold Castro Baltazar                                       3
Kristina de Leon Guillermo                                   3
Jason  Chua                                                  3
```

How will i make the count specific to the idcandidate?
Your great help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Julio Soares do you have any Idea or suggestion how will I address my problem?

Comment: I do... am trying to answer in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT fName||' '||mName||' '||lName, votes FROM (
SELECT a.idcandidate, COUNT(b.idcandidate) votes
FROM tbl_candidates a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT president idcandidate from tbl_votes
UNION ALL
SELECT vicePresident idcandidate from tbl_votes
UNION ALL
SELECT secretary idcandidate from tbl_votes
UNION ALL
SELECT treasurer idcandidate from tbl_votes
UNION ALL
SELECT rep1 idcandidate from tbl_votes
UNION ALL
SELECT rep2 idcandidate from tbl_votes
UNION ALL
SELECT rep3 idcandidate from tbl_votes ) b
ON (a.idcandidate = b.idcandidate)
GROUP BY a.idcandidate ) tab 
JOIN tbl_candidates b on (b.idcandidate = tab.idcandidate)
```

The above answer was for SQLite, I somehow misread the tags on this question.

However it probably works, except the first line would need to be in mySQL format:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", fName, mName, lName), votes FROM (
```

Comment: Your code works, it also shows the candidates that doesn't have votes. Thank you for your great help!

Answer (score 2):

Whereas you *could* approach this with a `CROSS JOIN` (but a different one than you propose) and appropriate aggregation of the results, that's a poor approach that would not scale well.  Of course, there are no really good approaches when you are saddled with a crummy data model, as you are.

There are several ways to approach this, none of them especially good, for instance:

```
SELECT `Name`, COUNT(*) AS `votes`
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fName, ' ', mName, ' ', lName) as `Name`
  FROM
    tbl_candidates c
    JOIN tbl_votes v
      ON c.idcandidate = v.president
  WHERE
    c.position = 'president'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    CONCAT(fName, ' ', mName, ' ', lName) as `Name`
  FROM
    tbl_candidates c
    JOIN tbl_votes v
      ON c.idcandidate = v.vicePresident
  WHERE
    c.position = 'vice president'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    CONCAT(fName, ' ', mName, ' ', lName) as `Name`
  FROM
    tbl_candidates c
    JOIN tbl_votes v
      ON c.idcandidate IN (v.rep1, v.rep2, v.rep3)
  WHERE
    c.position = 'representative'
) vote_agg
GROUP BY `Name`
```

That breaks down the problem by position, using one inline view for each position to generate a row for each vote for each candidate for that position.  It then combines them into an overall list via `UNION ALL`, and performs an aggregate query on the result to count the votes for each candidate.

If there were any votes for an existing candidate for a position that they are not running for (which is difficult or impossible to prevent via constraints on the specified data model), then those would be ignored.  If any one ballot had more than one vote for the same representative candidate, then only one would be counted (maybe the desired behavior, and maybe not).

Comment: Bolinger  Thank you so much for your answer! I was able to quickly analyze your answer. I got my query just the way i wanted

Answer (score 0):

you have problems with your model... once you address these the queries would be very simple to create.

Minimaly...:

I would create a positions table so I could directly relate to candidates.

```
positons_table
id     position
1      president
2      vice-president
3      secretary
4      ....
```

Then candidates table...

```
idcandidate  fName         mName         lName         position
1            Jefferson     Garcia        Roxas         1
2            Carlson       Mcvoy         Zafiro        1
3            Andrew        Efron         Anderson      2
4            Jessica       Garcia        Roxas         3
```

Then if you don't want to change your tbl_votes...

Votes for president:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.fName, " ", c.mName, " ", c.lName) as Name, count(v.president) as votes 
FROM tbl_votes v
INNER_JOIN tbl_candidates c on v.president = c.idcandidate GROUP BY v.president
```

Votes for vice-president

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.fName, " ", c.mName, " ", c.lName) as Name, count(v.vicePresident) as votes 
FROM tbl_votes v
INNER_JOIN tbl_candidates c on v.vicePresident = c.idcandidate GROUP BY v.vicePresident
```

and so on...
If you need to summarize all together...

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.fName, " ", c.mName, " ", c.lName) as Name, count(v.president) as votes 
FROM tbl_votes v
INNER_JOIN tbl_candidates c on v.president = c.idcandidate GROUP BY v.president

UNION

SELECT CONCAT(c.fName, " ", c.mName, " ", c.lName) as Name, count(v.vicePresident) as votes 
FROM tbl_votes v
INNER_JOIN tbl_candidates c on v.vicePresident = c.idcandidate GROUP BY v.vicePresident

UNION ....
```

Comment: I think you mean `c.idcandidate` in those queries.  Neither the OP's version of the candidates table nor yours as an `id` column.